# How to secure an IIS Site (HTML One) to be available only within a specific domain?

Tags: iis, iis-7, authentication

I'm wondering if there is a way to secure an IIS site (Static HTML Pages) to be available only within a specific domain (i.e. user should submit his domain user name and password to browse the site)?

P.S. I'm using IIS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to password protect a site is to change Authentication so that Anonymous Authentication is disabled and Windows Authentication is enabled.  Then on your NTFS permissions on disk, assign just the app pool identity + Administrators + SYSTEM + all of the domain users (or a group is better) that need access to the site.